# How to force a fetch in Relay modern

Tags: relayjs

My top-level component includes a settings dialog that includes the user's credentials.  When a change is made in that dialog and the dialog is dismissed (state is changed to `dialogOpen=false`), I want to force a new fetch from the server since the credentials may have changed. In Relay classic, the top-level component includes a Relay.RootContainer and so I just passed `forceFetch=true` to that RootContainer. In Relay modern, my top-level component includes a QueryRenderer. So how do I force the refetch in this case?

I found this issue, https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1684, which seems to indicate that the QueryRenderer *always* refetches, but this doesn't seem to be the case in my testing.  At least, I'm not seeing my fetchQuery get called after the state change/refresh when the settings dialog is closed. I think I'm probably not completely understanding the statements in that issue.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I think I figured out my disconnect here. In checking the source for QueryRenderer (don't know why I didn't do this in the first place), I saw that a fetch will occur if `props.variables` changes.  So I just defined a boolean instance variable called `refetch` and flip its value when my dialog is dismissed:

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={environment}
  query={query}
  variables={{refetch: this.refetch}}
```

Since this doesn't seem to well documented, I'll mention here that QueryRenderer will re-fetch when any of the following conditions is true:

- current `query` parameter is not equal to the previous `query` parameter.
- current `environment` parameter is not equal to the previous `environment` parameter.
- current `variables` parameter is not equal to the previous `variables` parameter.

Comment: That's all great, but do you have an idea how to force fetch, i.e. do not use cache?

Comment: @plamenh I believe you add the key `fetchPolicy={"network-only"}`

Comment: Just wanted to share some experience for anyone that might face the same issues: Change the variables only when needed (i.e. don't change the variables in order to refresh the data, but change them if you want to change the data that is retrieved - e.g., lazy loading); if you want to just refresh the data (i.e. when you are not using subscriptions to get fresh data or you have a mixed graphql/rest environment), use Refetch Container (see relay docs, it's well explained there).

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`retry` function](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/query-renderer.html) that's passed to `QueryRenderer`'s `render`.

```
<QueryRenderer
  environment={environment}
  query={graphql`
    query MyQuery($exampleUserId: String!) {
      user(userId: $exampleUserId) {
        favoriteIceCream
      }
    }
  `}
  render={({ error, props, retry }) => {
    // Here, you could call `retry()` to refetch data
    // or pass it as a prop to a child component.
    return (
      <IceCreamSelectionView refetchData={retry} user={props.user} />
    )
  }} />
```